# Turning off Psoc control register for more than 3 seconds

Tags: psoc

I am a novice at electronics as well as psoc so forgive me here... I have an application that uses a control register with 7 outputs... From what I can understand, when I call `I_Control_Reg_Write(0)` I turn it off, and if I call `I_Control_Reg_Read()` first and use the value I read from that and call `I_Control_Reg_Write(value)` that it will turn this Control Register back on?

To give you more insight on what I am doing.... when program first boots up, it is doing this...

```
TX_ena_Write(0);
I_Control_Reg_Write(0x02);

uint8_t mytemp = I_Control_Reg_Read();   
I_Control_Reg_Write (mytemp & 0x0f);
```

Then when turning the registers off I am doing this...

```
g_RegValue = I_Control_Reg_Read();
I_Control_Reg_Write(0);
```

To turn it on,

```
I_Control_Reg_Write(g_RegValue);
```

Which the code chunks above work if I turn off the register for 3 seconds, and turn in on for 1 second... But once I leave it off for more than 3 seconds, I can't seem to turn it back on....